# Searching a table based upon guid value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, guid

I need to find a row in a table based upon Guid value. This is what I've currently been doing and doesn't work.
I have a following function

```
public ActionResult Details(long id)
        {
            var ownerId = _dbSis.OwnedModules.Find(id);
            var ownerName = _dbCore.BusinessUnits.Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId);
            var moduleV = (_dbSis.Modules.Select(module => new ModuleDetails
                {
                    Id = id,
                    ModuleId = module.ModuleId,
                    TypeName = module.ModuleType.TypeName,
                    KindName = module.ModuleType.ModuleKind.KindName,
                    Owner = ownerName.Name,

                }));

            return View(/*moduleV.FirstOrDefault()*/);
        }
```

Currently I get null value in `ownerName` whereas in `ownerId` value is passed.
Here is the image of of what is passed in ownerId
[image]

Here is the image of the `BusinessUnits` table
[image]

Why isn't my `_dbCore.BusinessUnits.Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId)` not working or finding any value? Isn't it possible to Find some row based on Guid Value?

Comment: I can't see any reason why that shouldn't work. Never tried find with GuiId but I can't see any documentation that shows it won't work (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx). Have you checked that BusinessUnits actually has items at that point in your code as well (not just in the database)?

Comment: Umm it may sound stupid but, how do I check if BussinessUnits has items at that point. When i run the application and click on `BussinessUnits` at the line `var ownerName = _dbCore.BusinessUnits.Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId);` I get a setting sign and on clicking + sign, on the right side it says `count=0`. Does that mean there is no row at that moment?

Comment: Well you could either do a .Count() and see what that is or yes use IntelliSense to see if it has a count. You should also be able to enumerate the collection to actually see the values. However if count is 0 it will show nothing. If you hover over _dbCore.BusinessUnits and it shows count = 0 then I think you ahve your answer.

Comment: Silly question, but those annoying issues have silly cause in most cases. If you are using Entity Framework, are you sure, that the "Id" Property for "BusinessUnits" is marked as Identity? Maybe try change the code to something like dbCore.BusinessUnits.Single(x=>x.Id == ownerId.ModuleOwnerId) and see if that works

Comment: @Botis Yes it is marked as identity. I found that `_dbSis` which is of type `SISContext` inherits from `CoreContext`. So, instead of doing `_dbCore.BusinessUnits.Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId);` if I do `var ownerName = _dbSis.Set<BusinessUnit>().Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId);` it works. Not sure if I should put it as answer though.

Comment: Hmm... if it inherits, then you should be able to access the BusinessUnits from the _dbSis variable.. if so, why not do a simple join?